# Load KML to GeoJSON

Tags: leaflet, javascript, markers

I want to let Marker to other style.

This is my code:

```
<script>   

    var url = 'leaflet/WGS84.kml';
    doSomething(url);

    function doSomething(url) {
        var runlayer = omnivore.kml('leaflet/WGS84.kml').on('ready', function (layer) {
            this.eachLayer(function (value) {
            });
            var a0 = runlayer.toGeoJSON().features.length;
            var array = [], array2 = [];
            var array1 = [], array3 = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < a0; i++) {
                if (runlayer.toGeoJSON().features[i].geometry.hasOwnProperty("coordinates")) {
                    var a1 = runlayer.toGeoJSON().features[i].geometry.coordinates.length;
                    //for (var j = 0; j < a1; j++) {
                    array2 = [runlayer.toGeoJSON().features[i].geometry.coordinates[1], runlayer.toGeoJSON().features[i].geometry.coordinates[0]];
                    array.push(array2);
                    //}
                    var myMarker = new L.marker(array2).addTo(map);
                    array = [];
                }
                else {
                    /*
                    var a2 = runlayer.toGeoJSON().features[i].geometry.geometries.length;
                    for (var k = 0; k < a2; k++) {
                        var a3 = runlayer.toGeoJSON().features[i].geometry.geometries[k].coordinates.length;
                        for (var l = 0; l < a3; l++) {
                            array3 = [runlayer.toGeoJSON().features[i].geometry.geometries[k].coordinates[l][1], runlayer.toGeoJSON().features[i].geometry.geometries[k].coordinates[l][0]];
                            array1.push(array3);
                        }
                        var polyline = L.polyline(array, { color: 'red' }).addTo(map);
                        array1 = [];  
                     */
                }
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

Comment: What exactly does it mean 'This line can't work'? What is the content of `array` when you try to add new marker?

Comment: Oh,I found the problem,"var myMarker = new L.Marker(array2).addTo(map);" This is right code. And I want to know how can let Marker convert to other style?

Comment: Reading documentation can be sometimes of some help: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#marker

Comment: Thank you! I do it successfully.